# Est-il courant de parler d'éviter une « chauffe » d'un moteur, etc. ?

Tags: usage, préfixes

Un responsable autoroutier distribuant des bouteilles d'eau commente en disant :

> De quoi « s’hydrater » et « se prémunir potentiellement d’un risque de
> [**chauffe**](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chauffe) du moteur » (AFP ds. [LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2023-08-19/le-sud-de-la-france-sous-un-dome-de-chaleur.php))

On doit comprendre [*surchauffe*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/surchauffe) du moteur je crois.

S'agit-il d'une réduction du mot « surchauffe », est-ce usuel, a-t-on d'autres exemples de mots réduits par abandon du préfixe ([*sur-*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sur-) ici) ?

Comment: Je pense que tu vas loin dans l'analyse, cela relève plus du bon sens et de l'adaptation. Il paraît assez évident qu'une chauffe du moteur est une surchauffe dans ce contexte, mais ce vocabulaire est propre à la personne qui l'a employé, je dirais que c'est une expression un peu désuète, cad la personne qui l'utilise doit être sensiblement âgée. Un prof de français te dira qu'il s'agit d'un euphémisme.

Comment: C'était ma première réaction aussi - just une expression particulière à ce locuteur, sans grand problème.

Comment: @Frank Si on me demande d'avoir un _problème_ qui m'empêcherait de dormir, je contribuerais 1-2 fois par année.

Comment: @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t Je voulais juste dire qu'on n'a pas de problème de compréhension, même si l'expression est effectivement un peu surprenante :-) Pour le reste de ta question, c'est trop pointu pour moi, je ne sais pas :-)